# RPC binding handle

Tags: binding, rpc

I'm trying to understand what RPC binding handle is (DCE1.1 Remote procedure call).
Does the binding handle is valid as long as the connection between the RPC client and server is active?
What happens when the connection is lost (unexpectedly)? Does the client needs to bind again, receiving a new binding handle? 
Or does the handle can be used by the RPC client on multiple connections to the server?
Thanks!